# FetchRow in the detail table

Tags: delphi

I have a Master Table "Table1" and another detail "Table2". The detail table can contain more than one million records. So, not to load all these records when starting the application, I used "FetchRow".

When I launch the application, the "FetchRow" (set to 25 records) works without problems, I get 25 records. BUT when I switch to another Master Table record ("Table1"), the "FetchRow" does not work, that is, there are all the records that are displayed.

How to keep the "FetchRow" when I go from one record to another in the master table please?

Delphi XE5 + ZEOSDBO-7.1.4-stable + Firebird-2.5.6.

Comment: Do you mean that when you switch to another master record, the app attempts to retrieve all the million+ rows in the detail table, or just more than 25?

Comment: I mean that when i switch to another master record, the application retrieve all the million of the detail table.